# I how to intersect a range of columns between two horizontal list?

Tags: python, list, intersection

At the code I'm writing I need to intersect two horizontal list like:

## listA:

```
('name1','chr1', 'aatt')
('name2','chr11', 'aaga')
('name2','chr11', 'aaaa')
('name3','chr7', 'gtag')
```

## listB

```
('chr8', 'tagt')
('chr1', 'tttt')
('chr7', 'gtag')
('chr11','aaaa')
('chr9', 'atat')

#This lists are compounded by one str per line, wich it has a "/t" in the middle. 
#Also note that are in different order
```

**How can I get the lines from the listA whose columns 2 and 3 intersect with the listB?**

## desired result:

```
name2   chr11   aaaa
name3   chr7    gtag
```

The solution is not just "set(listA)&set(listB)" because the list have different number of columns

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set_b = set(list_b)
result = [x for x in list_a if (x[1], x[2]) in set_b]
```

Comment: then to print the result as I want... for c1, c2, c3 in result: print c1, c2, c3... am I right?